# how to lazy load data for groups in AdvandedDataGrid in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

Load data on demand (lazy load data ) for groups in advanced data grid control.
When the user expands a node the flex component can make a webservice calla and retrieve data for this group.

ignoring the webservie part, I am trying to figureout how to do the UI part in AdvancedDataGrid ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try
itemOpening event or itemOpen event and do the call to webservice get the data and add in the dataprovider and refresh

link http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html#eventSummary